# popToRootViewControllerAnimated when user swipe back

Tags: ios, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have view A, view B and view C. I have pushed view B from view A and push view C from view B.

When user tap on back button in view C, I call popToRootViewControllerAnimated so that user won't see view B at all.

Problem is that if user swipe back in view C, they will still see view B. I don't want user to see view B at all and jump directly to view A. How shall I do?

I use xib currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change stack of NavigationController when ViewController C appears. Use below code:-

```
NSMutableArray *aMutArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[aMutArr removeObjectAtIndex:aMutArr.count-2];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = aMutArr;
```

I have removed ViewController B from the stack. So if your user swipes back he will be able to see ViewController A.

Answer (score 0):

you can turn off the swipe back feature

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

in that way the user can only go back by the button that you have provided